# frappe 10 script report with checkbox column

Tags: erpnext, frappe

I'm trying to add a checkbox column in my script report
the column is added but the checbkox is not clickable it shows as a disabled icon

I added the column like this in my .py file

```
def get_columns():  return [        {           "fieldname": "check",           "label": _("Check"),            "fieldtype": "Check",           "width": 50         },      {           "fieldname": "account",             "label": _("Account"),          "fieldtype": "Link",            "options": "Account",           "width": 300        }         ]
```

I added this in  frappe.query_reports[''] = {}

```
get_datatable_options(options) {
    return Object.assign(options, {
        checkboxColumn: true,
    });
},
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.